# library not found error

Tags: linux, gcc

I am trying to execute an exe but it is giving me following error:

```
./runprog.out: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Although the same was working fine with other system but on my new linux system it shows the above error.

The library libstdc++.so.5 is present (as an executable) at the address usr/lib64/

So, reading previous comments and answers to such questions I tried to provide the path in the ~/.bash_profile and in ~/.bash_rc as:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5
```

or
    export PATH=/usr/lib64:$PATH

My ~/.bash_profile looks like:

```
export AMBERHOME=/home/chemistry/phd/cyz148216/amber/amber14/
export PATH=$AMBERHOME/bin:$PATH
export MKL_HOME=$MKLROOT
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$AMBERHOME/lib
export CUDA_HOME=/home/chemistry/phd/cyz148216/cuda-5.0
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib:$CUDA_HOME/lib64
export DO_PARALLEL='mpirun -np 2'
export vmd=/home/chemistry/phd/cyz148216/vmd/bin/
export PATH=/scratch/chemistry/phd/cyz148216/DHANVANTARI/GENOME/ncbi-blast-2.4.0+/bin:$PATH
export BLASTDB=/scratch/chemistry/phd/cyz148216/DHANVANTARI/GENOME/ncbi-blast-2.4.0+/db
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5
```

After doing source~/.bash_profile and relogging also the error is the same.

If someone has some suggestions, kindly help.

Comment: Please use 'ldd' command on your library to check for missing dependencies. Also, your should use 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64/'

Comment: Please try with the file command : `file [executable]` ... If it's a 32bits executable, then a 64bits `libstdc++.so.5` will be "Not found". .... Please edit you post to include OS name and version.